# CakePHP if no data show message

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following in my view for a client that shows a list of appointments for that client:

```
<h3>Appointments</h3>

<table>
    <?php foreach ($client['Appointment'] as $appointment): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($appointment['date'],
                array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'appointment', 'action' => 'view', $appointment['id'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $appointment['type']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I want to wrap the table in a if statement that checks if any appointments exist and if not then show the following instead:

```
<p>Client has no appointments. <?php echo $this->Html->link('Book Appointment', array(
        'admin' => true,
        'controller' => 'appointments',
        'action' => 'add',
        '?' => array('id' => $client['Client']['id']))
    ); ?></p>
```

How would I do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement and [`empty`](http://ca.php.net/empty) to determine whether or not the client has any appointments.

```
<h3>Appointments</h3>

<?php if ( ! empty($client['Appointment']) ): ?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($client['Appointment'] as $appointment): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($appointment['date'],
                array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'appointment', 'action' => 'view', $appointment['id'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $appointment['type']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Client has no appointments. <?php echo $this->Html->link('Book Appointment', array(
        'admin' => true,
        'controller' => 'appointments',
        'action' => 'add',
        '?' => array('id' => $client['Client']['id']))
    ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```